# EXCEPTION while importing data from excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to get data from an excel file, 2010 excel file, and inset it into my database. I've downloaded all jar files i needed ( well i think ) but i'm having an exception about the theme document, i don't know what does that mean. If anyone knows something about this exception please help.

Exception i'm having :

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/ThemeDocument
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
        ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... more

My code :

```
private void importingdata(){
PreparedStatement pstm = null ; 
     try{   
         FileInputStream fis = null;  
         fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\Users\\Mylaptop\\test.xlsx");  
         XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);  
         XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
         XSSFRow row ;
         for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
         row = sheet.getRow(i);
         int ordre = (int) row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
         String statut = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
         String libelle = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
         String sql="INSERT INTO statut (id_statut,valeur,description_statut) VALUES   ('"+ordre+"','"+statut+"','"+libelle+"')";
         pstm= (PreparedStatement) maConnexion.ObtenirConnexion().prepareStatement(sql);   
         pstm.execute();   }
         System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table"); }
     catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
```

}

Can anyone help please

Comment: Did you [try the advice in the Apache POI FAQ entry on this very error message](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)?

Comment: Yes I did but still have the same error

Comment: So you swapped the jars, made sure they were correctly there at runtime, and it still happened? (Only the error sounds a lot like what you get if you missed one of those steps out...)

Comment: Yes I did all the steps but the error is still there

Comment: Have you ensured you don't have any other (perhaps older?) POI jars on your classpath? (There's a POI FAQ entry on checking that too)

Comment: Can u please tell me all the jars i need with versions also

Comment: In case I forgot some of the jars, or i'm using some old verions

Comment: Download the [Apache POI 3.11 beta 2 binary package](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/poi/dev/bin/poi-bin-3.11-beta2-20140822.zip), and you'll find all the jars you need in there!

Comment: Thank u very much for ur help Gagravarr, the error is no longer here. Now i'm having a nullpointerexception error don't know where is the problem, can u help please

Comment: I would suggest you ask a new question for that, and post both the code and the full stacktrace